# Where is the blacklist on Math.StackExchange?

Tags: discussion

A user is being abusive to me. He is adding comments that have no relation with my question, and is attacking me in Chinese. Maybe moderators do not understand Chinese, so nobody is deleting them.

In this question for example:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3113958/element-in-finite-number-of-borel-subgroups

Can I block that user? But I do not know how to block the user.

I do not know how to deal with this problem. I need help.

Comment: I have removed the tag blacklist because the tag is for the words and phrases blocked according to the tag usage. Btw, although he or she attacks you because of your off-SE behavior, flagging is the best thing you can do. Don't post unfriendly comments to fight back.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It is not possible for a user to block or to ignore another user on the site. 
(Only, in chat it is possible to put another user on "ignore.")

If you encounter an unfriendly or rude comment, and this is an isolated problem, please flag it. There is a symbol next to the comment.

If there is a pattern of behavior that is problematic, please flag a post (question or answer) where the problem shows up as "in need for moderator intervention" and explain the situation.

If necessary, moderators can suspend users that behave in a problematic way.

(Note: On the moderator side, flag-handling is different for flags on posts and comments, which is why I make the distinction.)

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that the issue of insults being lost in translation has come up before; I remember a previous meta thread where it occurred. So the free form flag is definitely better than any other kind of flag for these.

Comment: Are insults in Klingon acceptable?

Comment: @MarkFischler is this a trick question? Generally, insults aren't acceptable in any language.